# Azure DevOps CI/CD pipeline: Revert commit on failure

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, yaml, azure-pipelines

I am currently building an Azure DevOps CI/CD pipeline and if it fails, I don't want to keep the code that lead to the fail in my repository. So, if the pipeline fails, I want the repo to be reverted to the last version before that commit. I can't find any help on that. How does this option look like and how can I add this option to my .yaml file?

Thank you so much.

Comment: why? just run your code in a side branch

Comment: It would be a best practice to create a new branch, commit and test your code before merging into your main branch. You could accomplish your requirement using GitHub commands from the pipeline, but I would not suggest it. You should authenticate in your GitHub repository using a Token and change HEAD.

Comment: I'm still learning about CI/CD because we are trying to transition from GitFlow. Best practice of creating the other branch is part of GitFlow pattern and not CI/CD, correct? My understanding is that proper CI/CD changes are applied to main.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, you can use the **`git revert`** command to revert some existing commits.

In your pipeline, you can check out the git repository and the branch where you made the changes. Then run the **`git revert`** command to 'undo' some commits.

For more details, you can reference the following articles:

- [**Git - git-revert Documentation**](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert)
- [**Git Revert**](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/undoing-changes/git-revert)

However, as @GeralexGR has suggested, it is recommended that you'd better create a develop branch based on the default branch (main/master) and make changes on this branch. Then build and test the code on the develop branch. Once everything is good on the develop branch, you can create a Pull Request to merge the changes from the develop branch to the default branch.